# Непонятная ошибка в Android Studio 2.3.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вчера вечером работал над проектом, все было нормально, сегодня захожу и у меня ошибка во всех файлах

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_beatch__list__view);
```

везде где использую "R"

В логах

Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Comment: Сначала выполните Build -> Clean project, затем - Build -> Rebuild project

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: Вот пример, почему не нужно не использовать Git. :)

Comment: @Владимир не понял вас

Comment: Откатиться к предыдущему коммиту было бы проще

Comment: @V Teme Что не понятно то?! Учи Git и усё будет в порядке.

Comment: В проекте есть файлы 9-patch?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не создавал

Comment: Класс R не генерируется обычно из-за ошибок в xml 'ях

Comment: Вам действительно нужен Git (система контроля версий) в ней видны все мельчайшие изменения проекта и возможность откатить любую часть изменений(при условии что вы часто будете делать коммиты)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему изменив ссылку на файл .Java в файле типа .xml
По какой - то причине система заменила все ссылки... видимо я что то не так нажал.

```
 tools:context=",,,,,"
```

в этой строке была ошибка которая не выделялась

Answer (score 0):

В любой непонятной ситуации Build - Clean Project:)
[image]

Comment: Делал уже 100 раз